# Do permanently unmarried women need to go to the mikvah?

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, niddah

Is the purpose of a woman's going to the mikvah so that she can permit herself to a man (be he her husband or any potential husband), or is it for her own sake? The *nafqa mina* is that of a woman who will never marry a man. Women who fall into this category today might include those who are in long-term lesbian relationships, but for a more classical example you can consider the woman who is twice (or thrice) widowed, according to Rebbi and Rabbi Shimon ben Gamliel, in Yevamot 64b. Can such women avoid going to the mikvah, or is it still a requirement?

Comment: This may speak more to my ignorance than any deficiency in the question, but can you add the specifics of any other reason that a woman might have to go to the mikveh besides the marital one?

Comment: @yitznewton Tuma == bad. Alternatively, perhaps there is a mitzva of tevillah, or a prohibition of remaining impure unnecessarily.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: why is ritual impurity a non-issue for lesbian women?  can't it be transmitted to their partners?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman It could by contact, but that's generally not an issue people care about. In other words, they have no more concern than any other women who is certainly not married.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2049/mikvah-non-jewish-husband

Comment: I don't understand why you ask about a permanently unmarried woman more than about a currently unmarried woman.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a Tannaic dispute whether or not going to *mikveh* at the earliest time possible is an independent *mitzvah* (טבילה בזמנה מצוה או לאו מצוה) (see e.g. [Yoma 8a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=8&format=pdf)). According to this opinion, a woman would go to the *mikveh* irrespective of becoming permitted to her husband (as in [Niddah 29b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=37&daf=29b&format=pdf) where a woman was sent to *mikveh* many times to account for many permutations of when her earliest time to go to *mikveh* was, all the while remaining forbidden to her husband).

The Beis Yosef (Y.D. 197 s.v. הלכך מצוה) cites several opinions that are explicit that according to this approach, a woman should go to *mikveh* even when her husband is out of town.

And, more directly to your question, the *Shach* ([Y.D. 197:3](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5544)) says that according to this position, **unmarried women and widows** should be going to the *mikveh*.

The *halachic* consensus seems to be that *mikveh* on time is not a *mitzvah*, as the *Shulchan Aruch* [Y.D. 197:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5544) codifies that it is only a *mitzvah* when her husband is in town, as a function of the *mitzvah* of *p'ru u'revu*. However, several major Rishonim, including no less than Rabbeinu Chananel, held of this position.

Comment: +1 but note that Tevilah BiZmanah might not practically apply to basically anyone after Chumra DeRebbi Zeira (since she's not going to be going after day seven anyway because she 'needs' Nekiyim).

Comment: @DoubleAA Yeah, I considered getting into that. But Shach certainly assumes it is, otherwise he wouldn't have the proof that he thinks he has.

Comment: Y ez You should consider answering here as well http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69956/759

Comment: Why didn't you bring up Tevila Bizmanah there as well?

Comment: @DoubleAA I wasn't sure it answered the question as asked. The OP there wants to know what to do with the imperative implied in the verse, and this _halacha_ doesn't really directly address it. Think I should do it anyways?

Comment: Well I didn't know of any other Halacha that did. The machloket tevilah bizmanah mitzva can be directly tied to how to understand those (and similar) verses. There's also the concern of being tahor for the regel (which the op didn't know about but is relevant). Those are the two concerns I expected to see addressed in the answers. If you have other concerns to add (not tevillat ezra...) i'm all ears. The teshuva you posted is long enough that i wont get through it tonight for sure, so i'm not sure what other factors, if any, he's working with.

Answer (score 14):

[Rabbi Isaac ben Sheshet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_ben_Sheshet) was asked ([Responsum 425](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19989&pgnum=278)) why no rabbinic edict requiring unmarried women to regularly purify themselves in the Mivka was ever enacted in order to minimize the transgressions of those who engage in extra-marital sexual contact. (I note the whole basis of the question is that in the days when women regularly or even semi-regularly were involved in handling sanctified food, such a purification was clearly performed. Nowadays that is not an issue [with the possible exception of women who would visit the outer parts of the Temple Mount].) He responds that no enactment was made because removing the biblical Karet-bearing prohibition of Niddah would allow people to grant themselves leniencies in this matter. The implication is that the longstanding custom was for women to not visit the Mikva outside the context of a "kosher" sexual relationship. Such is I believe the accepted practice today as well.

Comment: Thank you, Double AA. It's a bit early for me to use that as a basis for post-SA halakha, but that at least shows me that the Rivash held this way, and that there's apparently nothing in the literature that precedes him to lead one to a different conclusion. In the event that somebody else can give me a fuller answer, I may end up accepting theirs instead, but this has answered my question for now. Thank you.

Comment: For people who are interested, the relevant part of the responsum above is on the following page, and commences with ומה שנפלאת איך לא תקנו טבילה לפנויה.

Comment: I remember being told that the story of Amnon and Tamar (the daughter of King David) was part of what eventually led to unmarried women no longer going to the mikveh (for niddah). I also remember hearing of a medrash about a woman who was saved from rape when she told the rapist that she had not yet gone to the mikvah (though that probably would not do any good nowadays).

Comment: @sabbahillel Amnon and Tamar is why they prohibited Yichud with a Penuya. Nothing about Mikva.

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong for unmarried women to go to mikva. I cant provide the source at the moment but will look for it. Since it makes them more 'eligible' for znus. [Here](http://sc.tapuz.co.il/shirshurCommuna-2986-26409604.htm)
פנויות לטהרתן, ומורים ליחידים ולעתים אף לרבים לילך ולטבול ומתירים את האיסור בק"ן טעמים", כתב הרב מצגר לרבנים. "אשר על כן בא אני בזאת לחזק ולבצר פסקם של ראשונים ואחרונים ולהודיע בשער בת רבים כי איסור גמור הוא לאישה פנויה, לטבול לטהרתה, וחובה למונעה ואסור לסייע בידה. והפורץ גדר ישכנו נחש". בעבר פרסמה הרבנות הראשית קריאות בנושא, וכמו כן פורסם מכתב של הרב עובדיה יוסף. קריאתו של הרב הראשי באה בעקבות שאלה שנשאל על רב שלכאורה התיר טבילת פנויה וכן בעקבות נוהג שהשתרש לאחרונה בקרב רווקות, בעקבות אמונה תפלה, ולפיו אם יטבלו במקווה וינהגו כמנהגן של נשים נשואות - יזורז זיווגן.

Answer (score -2):

there is a custom among even single umarried men to go to the mikva every friday before shabbat.

I have heard people say they cannot feel the holiness of shabbat without going to the mikve.

I once read that Rabbi Chaim Kanievsky was asked if it is bitul torah (Wasted time) if a bachelor yeshiva student goes to the mikva frequently. he responded that on the contrary this is a good thing.

my point is tahara helps a person in his religious service. if this were not the case, yeshiva bachurim would not be encouraged to take time out from their learning. tahara helps a person connect to the spiritual (see shaarei kedusha gate 4)

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: @Michoel Perhaps unmarried women also can't feel the holiness of Shabbat without going to the mikva

Comment: Are you saying women should go to the mikva often just because being pure is better? If so, perhaps you should state that explicitly, as that is an answer to the question that was asked (while this is not yet).

Comment: @DoubleAA I think it's going in that direction.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question

Comment: Can such women avoid going to the mikvah, or is it still a requirement?