# When can one pray after semen emission?

Tags: halacha, talmud-bavli

I read in Talmud Bavli that one cannot pray a certain period after seminal emission. There is a discussion about how long that period is.

What's the accepted halacha on this issue? Does one who had a nocturnal emission have to wait until the next evening or morning?

Comment: Can you provide a more precise reference to the Talmud?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38485/what-is-ezras-immersion-%D7%98%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA-%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%90

Comment: relevant: [Why don't men go to the mikveh after relations/ejaculation?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69964/11501)

Comment: @Yishai As I understand from the link, this rule was canceled?

Comment: The answer there is an incomplete review of sources, but the generally accepted halacha is that the requirement was canceled. It is still a good thing to go to the mikva, though.