# Mikveh or 9 Kav?

Tags: halacha, mikvah-ritual-bath

The Shulchan Aruch in [Orach Chayim 88:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.88.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) states:

> *Baal Keri* is permitted in Torah, reading the *Shema,* and
>   prayer without **immersion** and without washing with **nine *Kabs* of water,**

Is bathing in 9 *kav* of water equal to immersing in the *mikveh?* If not, is it permissible bedieved? If yes, how many litres is 9 *kav* according to Chacham Ovadia Yosef?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a more complex story, and the short answer is clearly no. For example a convert or a woman after her period or a male who would want to enter the Temple Mount can't go and pour *9 kavin* of water upon themselves instead of a *mikveh.* There were 10 decrees of Ezra ([Bava Kama 82a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Kamma.82a.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), among them the last one requiring a *baal keri* (person having a seminal emission) to go to the *mikveh* before engaging in prayer. This requirement is discussed at length from [Berakhot 21b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Berakhot.21b.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), and the conclusion is that in certain cases it is not necessary to go to the *mikveh.* In the case of nocturnal emission, one can pour these *9 kavin* of water instead of going to a *mikveh* in order to resume prayer even while still impure, which is roughly equivalent of 4 minutes of a shower, according to [certain opinions](http://dinonline.org/2014/03/16/shower-for-9-kabin/). However, this ordinance of Ezra was [annulled](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69963/15256) during the times of the Talmud, and this opinion is followed by the *Shulchan Arukh.* [Others say](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A4%D7%97_%D7%90) that it is still a good custom to pour upon oneself these *9 kavin* of water.