# Can a woman converting to Judaism go to the Mikvah during her period?

Tags: women, conversion-to-judaism, niddah, mikvah-ritual-bath, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

When Gentiles convert to Judaism, they are "[like a newborn](http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?id=11382)".

If I understand correctly, [there is no such thing as Niddah vis a vis non-Jews](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2050/5).

So, if I add those two together, I am inclined to assume that if a woman has just finished her period when she goes to the Mikvah for her conversion, not only is she Jewish, but she is in a state of purity from the very start, without counting 7 clean days, etc.

If that assumption is correct, what about if she were to go to Mikvah *during* her period?  Would her conversion be valid, or would her ongoing (or, really, new) state of impurity invalidate the immersion and, by extension, the conversion?

Comment: Why wouldn't her Tevillah be valid? Suppose a Niddah is finishing up being a metzora. She could still go to the mikva after her second tiglachat to remove tumat biah.

Comment: @double aa relevant? http://www.jewishpress.com/judaism/halacha-hashkafa/daf-yomi-31/2012/06/27/0/?print

Comment: https://baisdovyosef.com/2336-rebirth-in-purity/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According an unsourced answer on Yoatzot.org, yes she can, even with active bleeding. I'm wondering why active bleeding wouldn't have Chatzizah problems, though.

The link to the answer has died in their recent reorganization of their Q & A section.

Comment: I wish they cited their sources, but barring a better-sourced answer, check to you.

Comment: Please someone tell me they discourage this in practice. Something used to stop the blood might be chatzizah, and if there were nothing, it would be extremely unhygienic

Comment: @SAH It still might be relevant after a short flow when she is done bleeding but hasn't yet reached 7 days.